Voluntary personal information
Where can I find plain text passwords with associated email address or username that are known to be in the 2017 Edmodo data breach?
Ideally, these should be people voluntarily giving their own password and username/email address for research purposes, and have either changed or not reused this password on other sites. Other sources are good too.
